# Scrolling with mousewheel leads to lag in jquery-coupled div

Tags: jquery, html

Div A's Scroll-Top is linked to Div B's Scroll-Top like this:

```
$("#A").on("scroll", function () {
    scrollTop = $("#A").scrollTop();
    $("#B").scrollTop(scrollTop);
});
```

My problem is that scrolling in Div B using the mousewheel leads to a noticeable lag in Div A following. Is there any workaround or a better event to attach the handler to?

**EDIT**
Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F4QdX)

Should have tested this before, but seems it's an IE thing .. works smoothly in FF and Chrome, but I am looking for an IE9 compatible solution.

Comment: It'd be nice to have a live demo, a fiddle or something. Hard to debug without it.

Comment: Here, my first fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F4QdX/     When creating this in FF, I wondered why it was scrolling so smooth .. I then tried the fiddle in IE9 and noticed a minimal lag.

Comment: well, no lag in firefox 23.

Comment: also good in chrome v28 :P Well won't help here, there ain't no IE on my system.

Comment: Lucky you, I guess..:o)